# Clock-wise case fan

Tags: cooling, fanless

I'm in need of a fan with 3 simple requirements.

1. it must be in the 140x140mm or 120x120 ATX case fan form factor.
2. it must run on 12VDC.
3. from the side which the air flows in, the fan *must* spin clockwise.

Preferably less than 25$ US.

I've found that this task is exceedingly hard, and that the majority of fans spin counter clockwise from the inward pulling face.